# is this a array memory leaks in angular?

Tags: angular, debugging, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools

as you can see in the attached image, I am debugging to find out the memory leaks in my application.
Under "array" entry there is a very high delta! "system" too, and the memory heap goes from 6MB to 11MB by switching between the home page (where there is nothing) and the gallery 20 times.
The ngrx dispatches and selectors are used in the gallery, I pass the data to the gallery component with the async pipe. I'm talking about the gallery component because by excluding it, commenting on it, the memory leak is no longer there.

First of all I would like to know if this is actually a memory leak and if it is I would like to know how to eliminate it. Since these are arrays, shouldn't they be deallocated upon component destruction? and what about "system" delta? Thanks!
[github](https://github.com/AndreaDiCioccio/NewCarsMarketPlace)
[image: memory leak]

**conteiner component**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-conteiner-gallery',
    template:`
        <app-gallery [allCars]="allCars$ | async" 
                    [brands]="brands$ | async" 
                    [types]="types$ | async" 
                    [usersRatings]="usersRatings$ | async" 
                    [recentSeenCars]="recentSeenCars$ | async"
                    [observedCars]="observedCars$ | async"
                    
                    (setObservedCarAction)="onSetObservedCar($event)"
                    (setNotObservedCarAction)="onSetNotObservedCar($event)"
                    (setObservedCarsAction)="onSetObservedCars($event)"
                    (setBrandChecked)="onSetBrandChecked($event)"
                    (setBrandsChecked)="onSetBrandsChecked($event)"
                    (setTypeChecked)="onSetTypeChecked($event)"
                    (setTypesChecked)="onSetTypesChecked($event)">
        </app-gallery>
    `
})

export class ConteinerGalleryComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{

    allCars$:Observable<Car[]>
    brands$:Observable<BrandCB[]>
    types$:Observable<TypeCB[]>
    usersRatings$:Observable<UserRating[]>
    recentSeenCars$:Observable<RecentSeenCar[]>
    observedCars$:Observable<ObservedCar[]>

    unsubscription$:Subject<boolean> = new Subject

    isStoreLoaded:boolean = false
    isStoreRecentSeenCarsLoaded:boolean = false

    constructor( private store:Store<StoreState>, private authService:AuthenticationService){}

    ngOnDestroy():void{
        this.unsubscription$.next(true)
        this.unsubscription$.complete()
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {

        this.store.pipe(select(statusSelectors.isStoreLoaded))
            .pipe( takeUntil(this.unsubscription$))
            .subscribe( loaded => this.isStoreLoaded = loaded)

        this.store.pipe(select(statusSelectors.isRecentSeenCarsLoaded))
            .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscription$))
            .subscribe( loaded => this.isStoreRecentSeenCarsLoaded = loaded)

        !this.isStoreLoaded ? this.store.dispatch(carsActions.getAllCars()) : null
        !this.isStoreLoaded ? this.store.dispatch(brandsActions.getBrands()) : null
        !this.isStoreLoaded ? this.store.dispatch(typesActions.getTypes()) : null
        !this.isStoreLoaded ? this.store.dispatch(userRatingsActions.getUsersRatings()) : null

        if(!this.isStoreRecentSeenCarsLoaded && this.authService.currentUserValue){
            this.store.dispatch(recentSeenCarsActions.getRecentSeenCars())
            this.store.dispatch(statusActions.setRecentSeenCarsLoaded({loaded:true}))
        }

        if(!this.isStoreLoaded)
            this.authService.currentUserValue ? this.store.dispatch(observedCarsActions.getObservedCars()) : null

        this.store.dispatch(statusActions.setStoreLoaded({loaded:true}))

        this.allCars$ = this.store.pipe(select(carsSelectors.getAllCars))
           
        this.brands$ = this.store.pipe(select(brandsSelectors.getBrands))
            
        this.types$ = this.store.pipe(select(typeSelectors.getTypes))
        
        this.usersRatings$ = this.store.pipe(select(userRatingsSelectors.getUsersRatings))

        this.recentSeenCars$ = this.store.pipe(select(userRecentSeenCarsSelectors.getUsers))

        this.observedCars$ = this.store.pipe(select(userObservedCarsSelectors.getUsers))
            
    }

    onSetObservedCar(carId:number):void{
        let observed:ObservedCar = {id:null, carId:carId, userId:null}
        this.store.dispatch(observedCarsActions.setObservedCar({carId}))
    }

    onSetNotObservedCar(carId:number):void{
        this.store.dispatch(observedCarsActions.setNotObservedCar({carId}))
    }

    onSetObservedCars(cars:Car[]):void{
        this.store.dispatch(carsActions.setCarsWithObserved({cars}))
    }

    onSetBrandChecked(brand:BrandCB):void{
        this.store.dispatch(brandsActions.setBrandChecked({brand}))
    }

    onSetBrandsChecked(brands:BrandCB[]):void{
        this.store.dispatch(brandsActions.setBrandsChecked({brands}))
    }

    onSetTypeChecked(typee:TypeCB):void{
        this.store.dispatch(typesActions.setTypeChecked({typee}))
    }

    onSetTypesChecked(types:TypeCB[]):void{
        this.store.dispatch(typesActions.setTypesChecked({types}))
    }

    public logout():void{
        this.store.dispatch(statusActions.setRecentSeenCarsLoaded({loaded:false}))
    }
}
```

**gallery component**

```
export class GalleryComponent implements OnInit, DoCheck, OnChanges{

    @Input() allCars:Car[]
    @Input() brands:BrandCB[]
    @Input() types:TypeCB[]
    @Input() usersRatings:UserRating[]
    @Input() recentSeenCars:Car[]
    @Input() observedCars:ObservedCar[]

    @Output() setObservedCarAction = new EventEmitter<any>()
    @Output() setNotObservedCarAction = new EventEmitter<any>()
    @Output() setObservedCarsAction = new EventEmitter<any>()
    @Output() setBrandCount = new EventEmitter<any>()
    @Output() setTypeCount = new EventEmitter<any>()
    @Output() setBrandChecked = new EventEmitter<any>()
    @Output() setTypeChecked = new EventEmitter<any>()
    @Output() setBrandsChecked = new EventEmitter<any>()
    @Output() setTypesChecked = new EventEmitter<any>()

    filteredCars:Car[] = []
/*     brandsCB:BrandCB[] = []
    typesCB:TypeCB[] = [] */

    user:User

    iterableDiffer:IterableDiffer<any>

    checkboxBrandAll:boolean = true
    checkboxTypeAll:boolean = true

    leftConteinerClass:string

    faBars = faBars

    constructor( private authService:AuthenticationService, private iterableDiffers: IterableDiffers){
        this.iterableDiffer = iterableDiffers.find([]).create(null);
    }

    // evocata quando ci sono cambiamenti nelle proprietà di input
    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        // c'è bisogno di chiamare filterCars perchè oltre a filtrare le auto aggiorna l'array in visualizzazione
        changes.allCars ? this.filterCars(this.brands, this.types) : null        
    }

    ngDoCheck(): void {
        // used when observed buttons are pressed
        let changes = this.iterableDiffer.diff(this.observedCars);
        if (changes) {
            this.user ? this.setObservedCars() : null
        }

    }

    ngOnInit():void{
        this.user = this.authService.currentUserValue
        this.user ? this.setObservedCars() : null
        this.initFilters()
        this.filterCars(this.brands, this.types)

        this.showNormalLeftConteiner()
        window.addEventListener('resize', () => this.showNormalLeftConteiner())
    }

    // setta le checkbox degli "all" dei filtri a false se altre checkbox risultano selezionate
    initFilters(){
        let filtersBrands:boolean = false
        let filtersTypes:boolean = false
        this.brands.some( brand => brand.checked) ? filtersBrands = true : null
        this.types.some( type => type.checked) ? filtersTypes = true : null

        filtersBrands ? this.checkboxBrandAll = false : null
        filtersTypes ? this.checkboxTypeAll = false : null
    }

    // operazioni da effettuara al cambiamento di una checkbox dei filtri.
    checkboxChange(event, brand, type):void{

        let name = event.target.name;
        let checked = event.target.checked;
        
        let brands:BrandCB[] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.brands))
        let types:TypeCB[] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.types))

        //BRANDS
        if(name =='allBrands'){

            if(checked == true){
        
                brands.map(brand => brand.checked = false);

                this.checkboxBrandAll = true

                this.filterCars(brands, types)
                brands = this.countBrands(brands)
                types = this.countTypes(types)
                this.setBrandsChecked.emit(brands)
                this.setTypesChecked.emit(types)
            
            }else{
                this.checkboxBrandAll = true
            }


        } else if(name == 'otherBrands'){

            brands = brands.map( b => {
                if(b.id == brand.id){
                    return ({...brand, checked:checked})
                }else{
                    return b
                }
            })

            if(checked == true){

                this.checkboxBrandAll = false;
              
            }else
                brands.some( b => b.checked) ? null : this.checkboxBrandAll = true

            this.filterCars(brands, types)
            brands = this.countBrands(brands)
            types = this.countTypes(types)
            this.setBrandsChecked.emit(brands)
            this.setTypesChecked.emit(types)
        
        }

        // TYPES        
        if(name =='allTypes'){

            if(checked == true){

                types.map(type => type.checked = false)

                this.checkboxTypeAll = true
            
                this.filterCars(brands, types)
                brands = this.countBrands(brands)
                types = this.countTypes(types)
                this.setBrandsChecked.emit(brands)
                this.setTypesChecked.emit(types)

            }else{
                this.checkboxTypeAll = true
            }

        } else if(name == 'otherTypes'){

            types = types.map( t => {
                if(t.id == type.id){
                    return ({...type, checked:checked})
                }else{
                    return t
                }
            })

            if(checked == true){

                this.checkboxTypeAll = false;

            }else
                types.some( t => t.checked) ? null : this.checkboxTypeAll = true

            this.filterCars(brands, types)
            brands = this.countBrands(brands)
            types = this.countTypes(types)
            this.setBrandsChecked.emit(brands)
            this.setTypesChecked.emit(types)

        }

    }

    // aggiorna la proprietà "observed" di allCars
    setObservedCars():void{
        let allCars:Car[] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.allCars))
        let observedCars:ObservedCar[] = [...this.observedCars]

        allCars.map( car => {
            // se la car è osservata, setta "observed" a true
            observedCars.some( obs => obs.carId == car.id) ? car.observed = true : car.observed = false

        })

        this.setObservedCarsAction.emit(allCars)

    }

    // aggiorna l array per la gallery (this.filteredCars) con l'array modificato eventualmente nei filtri o nella proprietà observed (this.allCars)
    filterCars(brands:BrandCB[], types:TypeCB[]):void{

        let allCars = [...this.allCars];
        
        const checkedBrands = brands.filter(brand => brand.checked);
        const checkedTypes = types.filter(type => type.checked);

        let filteredCars:Car[];

        if(!this.checkboxBrandAll && !this.checkboxTypeAll){

            filteredCars = allCars.filter(car => checkedBrands.find(brand => brand.name === car.brand) && checkedTypes.find(type => type.name === car.type));

        } else if(!this.checkboxBrandAll && this.checkboxTypeAll){

            filteredCars = allCars.filter(car => checkedBrands.find(brand => brand.name === car.brand));
        
        }else if(this.checkboxBrandAll && !this.checkboxTypeAll){
        
            filteredCars = allCars.filter(car => checkedTypes.find(type => type.name ===car.type));

        }else{

            filteredCars = [...allCars];
        
        }

        this.filteredCars = [...filteredCars]

    }
 
    // conta le occorrenze di ogni brand, ad esempio ferrari(2)
    countBrands(brands:BrandCB[]):BrandCB[]{

        let br:BrandCB[] = brands.map( brand => {
            
            let count = 0;
            
            this.filteredCars.forEach( car => {
                brand.name == car.brand ? count++ : null
            })
            
            brand.count = count;

            return brand
        
        })
        
        return br
    
    }

    // conta le occorrenze di ogni type, ad esempio jeep(2)
    countTypes(types:TypeCB[]):TypeCB[]{

        let ty:TypeCB[] = types.map( type => {

            let count = 0;
            
            this.filteredCars.forEach( car => {
                type.name == car.type ? count++ : null
            
            })
            
            type.count = count;

            return type
        })

        return ty
    
    }

    showMobileLeftConteiner():void{
        this.leftConteinerClass = 'show-mobile-left-conteiner'
    }

    showNormalLeftConteiner():void{
        if(window.innerWidth >= 1051){
            this.leftConteinerClass = 'show-normal-left-conteiner'
        }else{
            this.hideLeftContenier()
        }
    }

    hideLeftContenier():void{
        this.leftConteinerClass = 'hide-left-conteiner'
    }

    onSetObservedCar(carId:number):void{
        this.setObservedCarAction.emit(carId)
    }

    onSetNotObservedCar(carId:number):void{
        this.setNotObservedCarAction.emit(carId)
    }

}
```